# Child menu won't open when clicking parent menu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm editing a Wordpress theme, and I can't figure out how to get the child menus to open when clicking the parent menus. Can I change any of this code to make it happen?

```
// expandable menus
var expand_link = $('<a class="menu-expand"><span class="screen-reader-text">' + js_i18n.next + '</span></a>');
var back_link = $('<li><a class="menu-back">' + js_i18n.back + '</a></li>');

$('.menu ul.menu-wrap').data('depth', 0);
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').after(expand_link);
$('.menu .sub-menu').prepend(back_link);
$('.menu .sub-menu').hide();

$('a.menu-back').click(function () {
    var parent_ul = $(this).closest('ul');
    menu_level_down(parent_ul);
    return false;
});

$('.menu-item-has-children a:not([href], .menu-back)').click(function () {
    var parent_ul = $(this).parent().find('ul:first');
    menu_level_up(parent_ul);
    return false;
});


function menu_level_up(parent_ul) {

    var depth = $('.menu ul.menu-wrap').data('depth');
    var old_depth = depth;
    var new_depth = depth + 1;

    parent_ul.show();

    $('.menu ul.menu-wrap').data('depth', new_depth)
        .addClass('depth-' + new_depth)
        .removeClass('depth-' + old_depth);

}


function menu_level_down(parent_ul) {

    var depth = $('.menu ul').data('depth');
    var old_depth = depth;
    var new_depth = depth - 1;

    parent_ul.hide(250);

    if (new_depth <= 0) {
        new_depth = 0;
    }

    $('.menu ul.menu-wrap').data('depth', new_depth)
        .addClass('depth-' + new_depth)
        .removeClass('depth-' + old_depth);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for sharing a code example. It doesn't seem like it's displaying right, can you edit the question to fix the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this event simply not with this much code. You can call to the menus of your **WordPress** website simply and then can add click events with **JavaScript**. Follow this **JavaScript** code:

```
jQuery('YOUR_MENU_CLASS li.menu-item-has-children > a').after('<span class="sub-menu"></span>');
var menuBtns = jQuery('.sub-menu');
jQuery(menuBtns).on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var el = jQuery(this).siblings('ul');
    var tl = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('YOUR_MENU_CLASS li ul').not(el).hide();
    el.stop(true, true).toggle(400);
});
```

By adding this **JavaScript** code you will able to handle sub-menus as much as depth.

Comment: You will need to add CSS as well for their better alignment and appearance.

Comment: For more details see this **FIDDLE** code: https://jsfiddle.net/abk6qymp/, click this link  and then you can the live view of above code ( URL: **https://jsfiddle.net/abk6qymp** )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that functionality already exists. The functionality I'm looking for is that when you visit the menu item with children, it will show the sub-menu, instead of the main menu. For reference, visit : https://displaysanddesigns.dream.press/project-gallery/.

Comment: Then i think you will need to create multiple navigation as per the pages. Then on a particular sub-link page you can trigger that navigation.

Comment: For that you can check this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/ ( May be Helpfull )